# Where to put specific logic in a laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm building a small app using Laravel 4, mostly for my own learning, whose aim is to calculate money owed between a group of people (like housemates) based on their payments.

I have a bit of experience with CakePHP so am trying to use my knowledge of MVC architecture to do this properly.

Ignoring all the Auth, migrations tables etc here is my database schema:

[image: database schema]

So essentially, say one "payer" makes a payment on behalf of the group there will be a record in `payers_payments` for each payer with the amount they paid and whether they are included in the payment (`pays (bool)`). `payments` will have the general info for that payment. The total amount of the payment is the sum of the `payers_payments.amount` related to that payment.

At this point feel free to stop me and tell me my db design is rubbish and can be done a better way.

My understanding is that "business-logic" (getting stuff from the database) obviously goes into the models.

How should I structure my app so that I can produce a "summary" page with a statement for all the payments vs the payers. I want to make something like this (made in a pure php version):

[image]

Essentially a few calcualations are required to get the data in this form. Where should they go? Any advice for structuring the app any better? Assume I have all base controllers and models going.

Comment: In Model. Any data processing, specially, from database should be occured in Model.

Comment: I use a Service Layer to perform this logic, just add your own logic and have Composer/Laravel autoload it.

Comment: @AnthonySterling could you elaborate on this? How to I make use of a service layer?

Answer (score 1):

you can define [relationship data model](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships) on `Eloquent`, and also you can processing that data in model, but about your tables relationship structure, let's take a look at your table's relationship, every payments has many payer and every payer have many payments! so this is `Many To Many` [relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29), and finally this tables forming a third table that make this relation possible `payers-payments` well! so let's see the result!

**Payer Model**

```
class Payer extends Eloquent {

    public function Payments()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('Payments');
    }
}
```

now you have Payements in your payer Model and payments can be accessible by id:

```
$Payments = Payer::find(1)->Payments;
```

there are many examples on Eloquent documentation.